# Emailing subscribers

Tags: php, tinymce, phpmailer

For emailing subscribers I have created a section in the admin part of my website which allows users to do this. I have been using the text editor TinyMCE to do this but I have been running into some issues when uploading images. Images will come through into my work email but outlook will only show some whilst gmail doesn't show any, just an outline of where the image should be.

I have been using php mailer for this but can't seem to find a solution to make outlook and gmail show the images. My question is, is there a way to sort this? Or am I over complicating this and if so what would a simpler way of going about this be? The emails are stored in my sql table.

This is the code for the the user to create the email:

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    convert_urls : true,
    theme: "modern",
    paste_data_images: true,
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
      if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
        $('#upload').trigger('click');
        $('#upload').on('change', function() {
          var file = this.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            callback(e.target.result, {
              alt: ''
            });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
      }
    },
    templates: [{
      title: 'Test template 1',
      content: 'Test 1'
    }, {
      title: 'Test template 2',
      content: 'Test 2'
    }]
  });
});
  </script>

  <style>
  .hidden{display:none;}
  </style>



    <form action='createEmail.php' method='post'>

        <div id="toolbar-container"></div>

        <p><label>Subject</label><br />
        <input type='text' name='subject' required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['subject'];}?>'></p>

        <p><label>Content</label><br />
        <textarea name='emailCont' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['emailCont'];}?></textarea></p>
         <input name="image" type="file" id="upload" class="hidden" onchange="">

        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

    </form>

</div>
```

and this is my createEmail.php page:

```
<?php

require_once('../includes/config.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'C:\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-master\src\Exception.php';
require 'C:\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-master\src\PHPMailer.php';
require 'C:\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php';



$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$body = $_POST['emailCont'];


echo $body;

$sql = "SELECT email FROM subscribers";

    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {


$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);


try {

   $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->SetFrom('donotreply@mydomain.com', 'Newsletter');
    $mail->AddAddress($row['email']);
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
   $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Username = '*********';
   $mail->Password = '*********';
   $mail->Port = 587;

       if ($mail->addReplyTo('********')) {
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

         //keeps it simple
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        // a simple message body
    $mail->Body = $body. "<centre><a href='http://localhost/jgross/unsubscribe.php'>Unsubscribe</a></centre>";



               //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            //The reason for failing to send will be in $mail->ErrorInfo

            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            $msg = 'The Newsletter was sucessfully sent<br>';
            header("Refresh:3; url=index.php");
            echo "The Newsletter was sucessfully sent<br>";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Invalid email address, message ignored.';
    }





}catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->errorMessage();
    $mail->smtp->reset();
}

 $mail->clearAddresses();



}
```

I don't if this means anything but for one of the images that don't come through on both outlook and gmail the image address is:

data:image/jpeg;base64,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......and it carries on like that

Could it be because of this that gmail and outlook see the image as potentially unsafe?

Comment: Solve one problem at a time; make absolutely sure your uploads work first, then look at your email issues. You can't force email clients to display images, and most default to not displaying them, however, you should have no trouble with images if you choose to display them, and generally speaking, this is not something PHPMailer has trouble with - inline or linked images work just fine.

Comment: I'm sure the uploads work, tried just doing echo on the content instead of emailing and the text and images always display. Just can't figure out why Outlook and especially Gmail don't like the images

Comment: If you're using linked images (we can't tell what you're doing without seeing code or an example message), test the image URLs extracted from a received message.

Comment: I've added  my code to my question

Comment: So if I just add an image src from a random website rather than upload from files it works fine. So it is just for some reason that outlook and gmail don't like the images when they have been uploaded from my files

Comment: I'd advise you not to use `data` URLs for images in email as they do indeed have compatibility issues. I'd generally recommend linking over including the images, but if you want to embed your images, add them using PHPMailer's `addEmbeddedImage` method and reference them with a `cid` in your HTML rather than using a data URL.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how to do that with what I am trying to do?

Comment: `$mail->addEmbeddedImage('/path/to/image.jpg', 'myimage'); $mail->Body = '<img src="cid:myimage">';`

Comment: Ah okay thanks but not sure how that would work with what I'm trying to do? The person who is doing the newsletter would not have access to the code and the images would change for each newsletter

Comment: In that case go with linked images. Including images within messages is generally a bad idea for newsletters.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help and advice with this, really appreciate it